# Compiler-specific issues with passing C++ i/o classes through C interfaces

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have a problem which seems to be caused by my compiler.  When I compile a DLL with Mingw, everything seems to work fine.  When I compile the DLL with MSVC, the code seems to block somewhere in `createMdl`.  The process is left at 0% CPU usage and I never return from the function `createMdl` function call below.

This code runs in a bit of a large remote environment, so to debug on my machine I created a skeleton describing the problem below.  Unfortunately, this code doesn't exhibit the behavior I'm seeing either, but does describe what I'm trying to do.

Application:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;
  boost::asio::io_service::work work(io);
  boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));

  HMODULE h = LoadLibrary("MyLib.dll");

  typedef void (*createMdl_fn)(void*);
  createMdl_fn createMdl = (createMdl_fn)GetProcAddress(h, "createMdl");

  createMdl((void*)&io);
}
```

DLL:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl createMdl(void* io)
{
    boost::asio::io_service*       io_svc = (boost::asio::io_service*)io;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), 12345);
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket   sock(*io_svc, endpoint);

    char* buf = new char[256];
    sock.async_receive_from( boost::asio::buffer(buf, 256),
                              endpoint,
                              [buf](const boost::system::error_code& e,
                                  std::size_t b){});
}
```

Can you see a flaw with this approach?  Is there anything volatile in this approach? If you think that the `(void*)` casting of the `io_service` is a problem, how would you do it while still using `GetProcAddress`?  Note that I get the same behaviour regardless of which compiler I use to compile my application.

The big problem I can see is that if I recompile the library with a new version of boost, the definition of `io_service` may change and that can cause problems, but that doesn't explain the problem I'm having right now.

Comment: Bit hard to tell - providing code that does not exhibit your problem isn't all that helpful for other people to diagnose the problem in your actual code.    The only obvious concern I see is that your approach relies on both the application and DLL being built with the same compiler.   Otherwise the round trip from `boost::asio::io_service *` to `void *` (in `main()`) and the `void *` to `boost::asio::io_service *` (in `createMdl()`) won't work.   Making the function `extern "C"` means you can pass a `void *`, but doesn't guarantee the actual object is laid out the same.

Comment: Yep, I saw that too.  I wish I could reproduce the problem in an environment with less than 100,000 lines of code.

Comment: If you pass C++ objects between different compilation units/DLLs/executables/whatever, you **must** build them with the same compiler, otherwise everything is absolutely guaranteed to explode and burst in flames. There is no need to cast pointers to `void*` or declare functions as `extern "C"` in this case.

Comment: One of my main issues is that the DLL-load functionality in my application is implemented in C, so I'm kind of limited to using C in the interface.  You've given me a very good hint though, so I'm digging into that interface to see what I can do

Comment: Actually, if you put that in an answer, I'll mark it solved now, then make some edits when I've completed the work.  That answer is good enough to get me going in the right direction.

Comment: if you have to use GetProcAddress for some function, you have to declare that function as `extern 'C'` to avoid name mangling, but you don't have to keep its signature C-compatible (so no need to pass everything as `void*`). Sorry about the conffusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass C++ objects between different compilation units/DLLs/executables/whatever, you must build them with the same compiler, otherwise everything is absolutely guaranteed to explode and burst in flames.

Different C++ compilers have wildly incompatible ABIs. This is in contrast with C compilers, wich *usually* have compatible ABIs on any given platform, and are safe to mix and match.

There is no need to cast pointers to void* or declare functions as extern "C" in this case. (Except functions that you use GetProcAddress on).

You can use different C++ compilers **only if** you limit data you share between them to builtin types and C-compatible structs. Never classes with virtual functions or access-specifiers, or pointers to members, or standard library types — in short, nothing that makes C++ different from C. If you do use different C++ compilers, you do have to declare functions and object visible across the border as `extern "C"`.

Using a C++ compiler from one vendor together with a C compiler from a different vendor is usually not a problem.